# Why does my insert not work?

Tags: javascript, forerunnerdb

I have the following code and just cannot find out why doesn't it add the goal to my ForerunnerDB. I did everything as in the example in the ForerunnerDB manual.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Barebones todo</title>
<script src="./js/dist/fdb-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scrypt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="return addGoal();">
  Enter goal: <input type="text"id="goalinput">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="retrieve()">Retrieve</button>
<div id="p"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my scrypt.js file:

```
var fdb = new ForerunnerDB();
var db = fdb.db("myDatabaseName");
var goalCollection = db.collection("goal");

function addGoal() {
    console.log("addig goal...");
    var newgoalname = document.getElementById("goalinput").value;
    console.log(newgoalname);
    goalCollection.insert({
        _id: 3,
    name: newgoalname,
    order: 99
});

    };
function retrieve() {
    var findings = goalCollection.find({});
console.log(findings);

//document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = findings;
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = findings;
}
```

Comment: A possible error is that you are missing a space between `<input type="text"id="goalinput">`

Comment: tried it. Now the page reloads after hitting the submit.

Comment: also had to change <form onsubmit="return addGoal();"> to <form onsubmit="addGoal(); return false;">

Comment: Don't forget that you don't need to provide an _id field. Forerunner will generate a random uid if you don't specify anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @Luigi Cerone noted the issue was the space between

```
<input type="text"id="goalinput">
```